# 18.04.5 -> 20.04.1: grub2 configuration failure

Tags: grub2, upgrade

During LTS upgrade I got an error message concerning grub2 configuration and the upgrade process stopped.

Reconfiguring reproduced the error:

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.04-1ubuntu26.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
```

Debbuging the configure scripts revealed that the error occured in /var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-pc.postinst, line 688:

```
671             if [ -z "$RET" ]; then
672               # Reset the seen flag if the current answer is false, since
673               # otherwise we'll loop with no indication of why.
674               db_get grub-pc/install_devices_empty
675               if [ "$RET" = false ]; then
676                 db_fset grub-pc/install_devices_empty seen false
677               fi
678               if db_input critical grub-pc/install_devices_empty; then
679                 db_go
680                 db_get grub-pc/install_devices_empty
681                 if [ "$RET" = true ]; then
682                   break
683                 else
684                   db_fset "$question" seen false
685                   db_fset grub-pc/install_devices_empty seen false
686                 fi
687               else
688                 exit 1 # noninteractive
689               fi
```

From the script's code I would guess that grub did not find any devices for installation. Why is that so and how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you trying figure out the issue with grub or grub2? Is grub2 is installed and working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and, at least for me, it seems I have solved it.

The problem seems to be caused by a replacement of my hard drive many years ago.

Thus the entry for grub-pc/install_devices in /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
was invalid or missing, and so grub-pc.postinst tried to ask for it.

Unfortunately grub-pc.postinst ran in non-interactive mode; this might be
the main problem.

Actually, I solved the problem with a temporary patch to grub-pc.postinst,
which simply set the grub-pc/install_devices variable to my new hard drive id.
But probably it should be enough to edit /var/cache/debconf/config.dat directly.
*Of course, this is not a general solution, since I hardcoded the device id.*

My patch:

```
--- grub-pc.postinst    2020-10-11 12:50:47.288340305 +0200
+++ /tmp/grub-pc.postinst   2020-10-11 12:47:05.433847886 +0200
@@ -549,6 +549,7 @@
           priority=high
           device_map="$(grub-mkdevicemap -m - | grep -v '^(fd[0-9]\+)' || true)"
           devices="$(echo "$device_map" | cut -f2)"
+          db_set grub-pc/install_devices "/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB_S246NWAG406372X"
           db_get grub-pc/install_devices
           valid=1
           for device in $RET; do
```

Extract of the resulting /var/cache/debconf/config.dat:

```
Name: grub-pc/install_devices
Template: grub-pc/install_devices
Value: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB_S246NWAG406372X
Owners: grub-pc
Flags: seen
Variables:
 CHOICES = /dev/sda (1000204 MB; Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB), - /dev/sda5 (2999 MB; /)
 RAW_CHOICES = /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB_S246NWAG406372X, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB_S246NWAG406372X-part5

Name: grub-pc/install_devices_disks_changed
Template: grub-pc/install_devices_disks_changed
Value: 
Owners: grub-pc
Flags: seen
Variables:
 CHOICES = /dev/sda (1000204 MB; Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB), - /dev/sda5 (2999 MB; /)
 RAW_CHOICES = /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB_S246NWAG406372X, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Samsung_SSD_850_EVO_mSATA_1TB_S246NWAG406372X-part5
```

Comment: Thank you Karsten for your report and proposal of a workaround. 

I worked around the problem in a different way: 
I simply purged and reinstalled the grub-pc package using
sudo apt purge grub-pc
sudo apt install grub-pc

During install I was prompted which drives to choose, so I could configure everything as needed.
Still, the root cause of the problem seems unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Manually reconfiguring the grub-pc package will cause it to show you the list of available drives again (and then install grub onto the drive(s) you select, as well as save the selections into the debconf/config.dat file):

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
[... some other prompts go by ...]
The GRUB boot loader was previously installed to a disk that is no longer
present, or whose unique identifier has changed for some reason. It is important
to make sure that the installed GRUB core image stays in sync with GRUB modules
and grub.cfg. Please check again to make sure that GRUB is written to the
appropriate boot devices.

If you're unsure which drive is designated as boot drive by your BIOS, it is
often a good idea to install GRUB to all of them.

Note: it is possible to install GRUB to partition boot records as well, and some
appropriate partitions are offered here. However, this forces GRUB to use the
blocklist mechanism, which makes it less reliable, and therefore is not
recommended.
                                    <Ok>

             ---------------- Configuring grub-pc -----------------             
             | GRUB install devices:                              |             
             |                                                    |             
             |    [*] /dev/sda (80000 MB; WDC_WD800AAJS-75M0A0)   |             
             |    [*] /dev/sdb (81964 MB; Maxtor_6V080E0)         |             
             |    [ ] /dev/md0 (9999 MB; ???)                     |             
             |                                                    |             
             |                                                    |             
             |                       <Ok>                         |             
             |                                                    |             
             ------------------------------------------------------
```

I generally use this approach to installing grub on the new hard disk immediately after replacing an old one, since that insures that the new drive is included in auto-installed bootsector updates when the grub packages are upgraded later.